# filling an area of a matrix with characters

Tags: c++, matrix, multidimensional-array, vector

I have created a matrix using 2D vectors. The code I used is

```
int RC=50;
vector<vector<int> > matrix;
vector<int>row;
///////////Building Grid//////////////////
for(int i=0;i<RC;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<RC;j++)
    {
        row.push_back(0);
    }
    matrix.push_back(row);
}
  //////////Printing Grid///////////////////
for(int i=0;i<RC;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<RC;j++)
    {
        cout<<matrix[i][j]<<" ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
```

The output of the above code is

[image]

Now what I want is to fill a block of size 6x6 inside the matrix with '$' or any character by inputting the bottom left location of the block. For example if i gave the location as (10,4), then I would like to place a block of '$' (size 6x6) whose bottom left co-ordinates are (10,4).

EDIT-1

I added the code

```
int si=3;
int sy=3;
 for(int i=0;i<RC;i++)
{
    for(int j=0;j<RC;j++)
    {
       if(i>=si && i<=si+6 && j>=sy && j<=sy+6)
       {
           matrix[i][j]=1;
       }
       else
       {
        matrix[i][j]=0;
       }
    }
}
```

and I got the output as

[image]

I am reading the co-ordinates as the top left ones, what should I do to read the co-ordinates as the bottom left ones and build the block from there?

Comment: So, what exactly is your question? You just described what you are planning to do.

Comment: sorry guys, Just updated the question

Comment: Just start iterating the rows from `i - 6` instead of `i` (assuming that `i` is walking the rows and `j` is the columns). That should work, no?

Answer (score 1):

You need to tackle the problem logically and break down the steps you need to solve it.  You're staring at a big block of zeros and that isn't going to help.  So, walk through it with pseudo code and a handy, dandy piece of paper and pencil.

Ask smaller questions about the larger problem at hand.  How do you go from bottom left coordinate to the coordinate you wish to start with?  How do you determine when to stop?  Do I understand what I just did?  If not why don't I understand it?

Baby step by baby step while you're learning.  Take the time to understand why something either worked the way you wanted it to or failed to work.  Do this and you'll be a much better coder for it.